# How to center the image source within an image tag?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm currently working on a colorbox-based gallery but I've run into an issue.
I have an image tag with a source that is resized according to the height of the image tag (because otherwise the background would be showing, which I don't want).

So, *very* basically what I have is this:

HTML

```
<img src="largephoto.png"/>
```

CSS

```
img {
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

A JSfiddle to show my whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/puqd2bn5/7/

But now the image isn't centered, which bothers me a lot.

How can I center the image source within the image tag, without changing the source into a background? (because that would mean I had to change the css for every gallery-item, which I don't want)

Edit:

So, currently I have this:

[image]

But I want the image centered WITHIN the image tag. So the booklet in the center of it's image tag.

Comment: you can set the image absolute and position it http://jsfiddle.net/puqd2bn5/9/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Yes, excellent! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it? What exactly did you change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the image absolute and position it horizontally by adding `left:50%` and `translatex(-50%)`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/puqd2bn5/9/

Comment: No problem ;). It helpen me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

well i guess it was this you wanted :)

change the .view img 
to:

```
 .view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   min-height:100%;
   height:100%;
   min-width:100%;
   margin:0 -100%;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

image parent div have width.
and image have a full width.

change .view class

from :

```
    .view {
        background: url("../img/background/patterns/bgimg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / cover #fff;
        cursor: default;
        float: left;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 19%;
    }
```

to:

```
    .view {
        background: url("../img/background/patterns/bgimg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / cover #fff;
        cursor: default;
        float: none;/*change float left to none*/
        height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 19%;
        margin:0 auto; /*add margin for show in center of body*/
    }
```

Comment: That's centering the image tag within the PARENT, I want to center the image source WITHIN the image TAG.